# Storing a multimap with jdo

Tags: java, sql, jdo

How would one serialize an `ArrayListMultiMap<String, String>` with jdo in the best way.
The preferred table structure would look something like

```
owner_id, key (String), Value(String), order
```

It is easy if the values are serialized as a blob. But we would like to adopt this so we can do queries as well.

---

`Map<String, List<String>>` would be fine as well instead of ArrayListMultiMap.

Answer (score 0):

You could serialize/deserialize the MultiMap to/from a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

Given that table structure I would assume `PRIMARY KEY` be as:

```
PK=owner_id, key
```

And then break your `Map<String, List<String>>` data structure into multiple rows like this:

```
owner key    value
100   key1   value11
100   key1   value12
100   key1   value13
100   key1   value14
100   key2   value21
100   key2   value22
100   key2   value23
```